# Unable to Apply Scikit-Learn Imputer To A Dataset With Two Features

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am trying to read in the complete Titanic dataset, which can be found here:

[biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/titanic3.xls](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/titanic3.xls)

```
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_excel('titanic3.xls')
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
x = dataset.iloc[:, 2:14].values

# Create Dataset for Men
men_on_board = dataset[dataset['sex'] == 'male']
male_fatalities = men_on_board[men_on_board['survived'] ==0]
X_male = male_fatalities.iloc[:, [4,8]].values

# Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X_male[:,0])
X_male[:,0] = imputer.transform(X_male[:,0])
```

When I run all but the last line, I get the following warning:

```
/Users/<username>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:395: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
```

When I run the last line, it throws the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-2-07afef05ee1c>", line 1, in <module>
   X_male[:,0] = imputer.transform(X_male[:,0])
   ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (523) into shape (682)
```

I've used the above code snippet for imputation on other projects, not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution is to change `axis = 0` to `axis = 1`. This will make it work, though I'm not sure if that's what you want. So I want to give some explanation about what happened here as following:

The warning basically tells you [sklearn estimator now requires 2D data arrays rather than 1D data arrays](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#id17) where interpreting data as samples (rows) vs as features (columns) matters. During this deprecation process, this requirement is enforce by [np.atleast_2d](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.18.X/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L384-L398) which assume your data has a single sample (row). Meanwhile, you passed `axis = 0` to the Imputer which ["impute along columns"](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) by `strategy = 'mean'`. However, you have only 1 row now. When it comes across a missing value, there is no mean to replace that missing value. Therefore the entire column (which contains just this missing value) is discarded. As you can see, this is equal to

```
X_male[:,0][~np.isnan(X_male[:,0])].reshape(1, -1)
```

That's why the assignment `X_male[:,0] = imputer.transform(X_male[:,0])` failed: `X_male[:,0]` is shape(682) while `imputer.transform(X_male[:,0])` is shape(523). My previous solution basically changes it to "impute along rows" where you do have mean to replace missing values. You won't drop anything this time and your `imputer.transform(X_male[:,0])` is shape(682) which can be assigned to `X_male[:,0]`.

Now I don't know why your code snippet for imputation works on other projects. For your specific case here, a (logically) better way in regarding to the deprecation warning could be using `X.reshape(-1, 1)` since your data has a single feature and 682 samples. However, you need to reshape the transformed data back before being able to be assigned to `X_male[:,0]`:

```
imputer = imputer.fit(X_male[:,0].reshape(-1, 1))
X_male[:,0] = imputer.transform(X_male[:,0].reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(-1)
```